# poetic effect of segmentation of a group of words

Tags: expressions, punctuation

Some poems break a sentence or a clause into two lines at the middle of one meaning group of words, like -

... a blue
sky and ...

What effect such an irregular line break has?

Mr. Garrison Keillor usually ignores such line breaks when reading poems in the Writer's Almanac radio program.

Comment: At least sometimes, the breaks are intentional -- for rhyme.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this, depending on the intent of the poet: rhyme, meter, physical appearance on the page are the most obvious ones that come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term you're looking for here is

> **enjambment** (n)
>    The continuation of a syntactic unit from one line or couplet of a poem to the next with no pause.

[TFD, American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: Poems that employ *enjambment* need not break arbitrarily in the way the OP's example shows, or in the manner he speaks about ("irregular") by which I assume he means lines of differing length. They can consist of (metrically) full lines; with *enjambment* the lines simply do not end on a major syntactic break; instead the line ends "in the middle of the clause" or phrase, so to speak, and the remainder of the clause or phrase continues on the next line(s).

Answer (score 1):

To take a
normal prose sentence and
make it look like
poetry,
all one needs do is
break the lines in
unusual places.
We are too easily
deceived.

Comment: That’s called *shameless enjambment*. [So is this.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5853584#5853584) :)

Answer (score 0):

Line-breaks in modern and contemporary poetry can be very arbitrary. Sometimes the poet wants to draw attention to the words in isolation; sometimes it's for rhythm; sometimes for rhyme; sometimes to disrupt the eye's progress; sometimes because the poets were paid by the line. The reasons for the practice and the effects of the practice vary greatly.