# Term for song or poem where the end of one line is also the start of the next

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, poetry, lyrics

[The Jonathan Coulton song "Sticking it to Myself"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfxkJH7gJjU) has an interesting style of lyricism in its second verse:

> Sticking it to my
>   **Self**-control; that's not the only thing **I lack**
>   A plan.
>   Just my own gun against my
>   **Back** down now and let this hostage
>   **Go** away.
>   I'm trying to figure **something**
>   Makes me feel
>   Like I'd do anything it takes to be
>   A f---ing winner now.

The end of each line also functions as the start of the next, yet isn't repeated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/239077/17956

Answer (score 0):

The word you are probably looking for is ***enjambment***. According to [this article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/11/14/how-jack-reacher-was-built) from The *New Yorker*, it is "the lit-crit term for a phrase in a poem that runs over into a second line." Oxford offers [this definiton.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enjambement)

> Read the question [poetic effect of segmentation of a group of
>   words.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208331/poetic-effect-of-segmentation-of-a-group-of-words/211537#211537)

Comment: In enjambment the portion that runs over only makes sense as part of one line, but in my case the word makes sense as part of both lines.